# Access Tomcat localhost:8080 of guest VirtualBox VM from Host OS

Tags: tomcat, localhost, virtual-machine

I have an XP laptop on which I am running an Ubuntu distro inside VirtualBox which is running a website via Tomcat. When I am in the VM I can access the site with localhost:8080/

What I really need to do, though, is to access the VM localhost from XP. vm-computer-name:8080/ isn't recognized.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the IP Address of your guest OS and access it via that.

Comment: What if you have multiple Tomcat's that are differentiated by name?  Such as public.mysite.org:8080, admin.mysite.org:8080, etc.

Comment: You have multiple tomcat's running in your VM?  If so, they would need to run on separate ports.  Or do you have multiple hosts setup in your tomcat config?

Comment: On centos8 atleast I had to disable the firewall before being able to access the tomcat on 8080 even though I was connected via bridged mode.
systemctl disable firewalld.

Answer (score 9):

Setup your VM to run a host-only network, then reboot or restart networking to update DHCP. The IP address on the guest will now be accessible from the host.

You can also use bridged network mode, but that won't work when the host is disconnected from the network.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Host only network was the key for me. If you use virtualbox you will need to create a network to be able to use this configuration. https://askubuntu.com/questions/198452/no-host-only-adapter-selected

Answer (score 2):

The following helped me after a new VM and tomcat installation.

Get the IP address of the Guest OS and the port number on which tomcat was started. Then you can access it via:

> IP:Port/

In case you are not able to access it still or if you get no response, try

> sudo iptables -F

This would flush the tables and would reflect the new mapping. You would need to do this only once though.

Answer (score 0):

Type the following command on VM and then try.

sudo iptables -F