# how to access django development server on virtual machine from actual computer

Tags: django, virtual-machine

Okay so I have my actual laptop which has vmware player installed. I am running lubuntu as a virtual machine and I installed django on the virtual machine and am testing my app so I did python manage.py runserver and I can access the app by visiting 127.0.0.1:8000 from my VM, however, If I go to 127.0.0.1:8000 from the actual computer (not the VM), it says 'chrome could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8000'.. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Have a look at similar topics:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261975/addressing-localhost-from-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155487/access-tomcat-localhost8080-of-guest-virtualbox-vm-from-host-os

Comment: What network mode do you adopt ? Bridge ? NAT ? Host-only ?

Comment: @JeffLi NAT.. when I try to change the network mode to bridge, my guest OS losses internet access.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to get @Kerberos answer to work. (not enough points to comment so I'm adding it as a seperate answer).

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in a guest OS in VMWare. The host laptop is running Windows 8.

As mentioned by Kerberos, in VMWare, go to `Player ==> Manage ==> Virtual Machine Settings...`

On the Hardware tab, select `Network Adaptor`, then select the radio button for `Bridged: Connect directly to the physical network`. Select `OK`

In the VM, the network connection information should now have the same IP address of the host OS internet connection. In my case: 192.168.1.141  (yours will vary).

In the VM, start Django using `python manage runserver 192.168.1.141:8000`

Using this method, I am able to access the webserver running in the VM at this IP address from within the VM, from host machine, and from other systems on the same 192.168.1.xxx network.

Comment: right, but my problem is that even thought I tried what you did, once I set the connection of the VM to 'Bridged' and hit okay, I was unable to connect to the internet from my VM. My IP address for the VM also did not change and when I tried running the server on my host OS's IP address, it gave an error saying 'that ip address can't be assigned-to' and I confirmed that the two lines which are suggested here: s/13505540/error-that-ip-address-cant-be-assigned-to-in-django are in my etc/network/interfaces

Comment: Okay so I just shut down my VM and restarted it and then bridged the network and it worked. After bridging, I also just ran the surver on 0.0.0.0:8000 and then accessed my VM's ip address (192.169.2.49:8000) from my host OS's Google Chrome and it worked.

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: This answer makes sense and actually works. Also, is there a way to configure this so that we don't have to type the full IP in the runserver command?

Answer (score 17):

You can try running the server on `0.0.0.0`

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

The IP address `0.0.0.0` means "all IP addresses on the local machine" (or all IPv4 addresses on the local machine).

Next, you will need the ip address of your VM. Visting http://<ip_address_of_vm>:8000 on other computers should access the django development server on your VM.

Note: If your VM only has an internal IP (e.g. 192.168.x.x) then only computers on the same network can visit the VM.

Comment: Hm, didn't work, so I did python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 and from the vm, went to 0.0.0.0:8000 and it worked. I then opened up the terminal on the vm and typed ifconfig, it says inet addr:192.168.174.132 so I went to 192.168.174.132:8000 from my computer but that didn't work.. any ideas on what's wrong?

Comment: I was able to do this, and connect on the host to `localhost:8000`. I have Virtualbox set up to use NAT and forward port 8000 on the guest.

Comment: There is a shortcut for doing this, if you run `python manage.py runserver 0:8000` then it is accessible from host machine (of course if you setup port forwarding etc.)

Answer (score 2):

to access virtual machine (guest) from outside the host computer, you have to set the guest network mode to bridge

Bridge-mode connects the guest to the actual network so that other machines can connect to it

Comment: I went to VMWare Player, clicked 'Player -> Manage -> Virtual Machine Settings' and then changed 'Network Adapter' from 'NAT' to 'Bridged'... after doing this, my guest OS couldn't lost internet connection. I ran the django server on 0.0.0.0:8000 and could access it by going to either 0.0.0.0:8000 OR http://192.168.174.233:8000/ from the guest OS, but I couldn't access it from either of the two links from the host OS.. any idea why?